# How to do unit tests of a storm topology?

Tags: java, apache-storm

I've been developing storm topologies, however I'm still finding that I'm lacking a proper way of unit testing the bolt and spout that have been created without having to launch the topology and send myself traffic.
The services used in the topologies is separated and unit tested but there could still be error with their usage or with the topology stuff (tuple incorrect, ect).
What is the way to create unit tests in my project in order to address this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds more to me like you're not talking about unit tests but about the next step - integration tests.

Comment: Well I did add integration tests, it helps a lot :) but it's slow and for me the basics like checking whether my topo is correct and each blot is sending/processing a correct tuple could be unit tested but I'm not sure what's the best way. Probably with Mockito but I hope there is something better.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit complicated to create a unit test for bolts, but it is possible **without deploying the topology**.
you can create a testing class that implements the IOutputCollector
and another testing class that implements the Tuple. 
you should implement the methods you use and probably store the emitted tuples.

afterwards you can create the bolt's unit tests with the following code.

```
MockOutputCollector c = new MockOutputCollector();
Bolt b = new Bolt();
b.prepare(c,null,null);
MockTuple tuple = new MockTuple(fields,Arrays.aslist({"a,b,c"}));
b.execute(tuple);
List result = c.getEmittedTuples().get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the complexity of the processing your are doing but an easy way for testing a bolt is to create an another bolt that do assert (using your favorite testing framework) on the tuple content in execute method.

```
class AssertOutput extends BaseOperation implements Function {

        private AssertOutput() {
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(final TridentTuple tuple, final TridentCollector collector) {

            final List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();

            for (final Object obj : tuple.getValues()) {
                values.add(obj);
            }
        }
}
```

So in an Unit Test you can easly check the output of your bolt by calling each method with AssertOutput bolt.

It's the only way I know to automate checking of the content of tuples.